Does the Gauss-Lucas theorem generalize to arbitrary entire functions with a finite number of zeros?
The Gauss-Lucas theorem states that if $P(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients, then all the zeros of $P'(z)$ lie within the convex hull of the set of zeros of $P(z)$.
Does this theorem generalize to arbitrary entire functions $P(z)$ with a finite number of zeros? If not, is there a counterexample?
(This question is a special case of the question at Extending The Gauss-Lucas Theorem .)

Did you check the example $f(z) = (z^2-1)^me^{az}$ given in the comment to the referenced question?

Also: $f(z) = ze^z$, $f'(z) = (z+1)e^z$.

This would also mean that if $f$ has no zeros then $f'$ has no zeros either, which is definitely wrong.

Gauss-Lucas does not extend to arbitrary entire functions with a finite number of roots.
$f(z) = (z^2-1)^2e^z$ has roots $\pm 1$, but it's derivative $f'(z) = e^z (z^2-1)(z^2+4z-1)$ has $(-2-\sqrt{5})$ as a root, which is clearly not in the convex hull.
